# Case sensitive folder names in MAMP

Tags: mamp, case-insensitive, case-sensitive

I'm not sure what site this question should be on, please feel free to move as necessary. I am working on a project in PHP where I need to differentiate between the folders 'a' and 'A'. When I run the script:

```
<?php

mkdir('A', 0700);
mkdir('a', 0700);

?>
```

Only 'A' is created. Is this a mac problem, or is there something in a config file that I can change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is something I think you set up while installing MacOS. 
If you have chosen non-case-sensitive - you'll have to back up your data... and reformat/reinstall.

This is what I found googling for your problem:
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=164713

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the filesystem, NTFS is case insensitive, ext3, ext4 etc is case sensitive, HFS+ can be either and is setup during partition creation.

I don't know if there is anyway to change this I've certainly not come across any method.